# Percentage Format in settext not correctly displayed

Tags: android, string, format, settext

I have programmed a small test and at the end the result is supposed to show a percentage. Currently there are three questions and the percentage is almost correct, e.g. 2/3 will show 66.0% instead of 66.7 or 67. 
Percentage is formatted as double and score as integer. Could that be a reason?
I have also tried calculating within the settext, but that did not work. Therefore I invented the percentage variable.

```
...
 else{
                //neue Frage oder Testende
                if(durchlauf < 3){
                    SetNextQuestion();
                }
                else{
                    qt.setText("");
                    rdg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    hintbutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    percentage = ((score * 100)  / 3 );
                    t.setText("Test abgeschlossen \n" + "Punkte: " + score + " (" + String.format("%.2f", percentage) + "%)");
                }
```

Comment: try using float instead of double

Comment: [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17) [basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> percentage = ((score * 100)  / 3 );
> ```

Right-hand side of this assignment is computed as integer and only then the integer result is assigned to a double. You might want to change the calculation to floating-point, too:

```
percentage = ((score * 100.0)  / 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you - I understand that now. Interesting that the calculation shows 66 instead of 67 though, but I guess the integer - calculation cuts out everything after the comma instead of rounding.